# C++ - Error: Expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, variables, syntax-error, variable-assignment

I'm creating a C++ application and I have a class which contains a `char` array variable, like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    // The constructor
    MyClass(char[]);
private:
    // The variable
    char myVariable[];
}
```

And I try to set this variable in a constructor like this:

```
// The constructor
MyClass::MyClass(char myVariable[])
{
    // Set the variable
    MyClass::myVariable = myVariable;  //<----- Error
}
```

but then I get an error (`Error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue`) on the line where I set the `MyClass::myVariable` variable on. I'm new to C++, so I have no idea about what this means. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not assign arrays using assignation operator (`=`)

You should `#include<algorithm>` and call the following

```
std::copy(myVariable, MyClass::myVariable, size_of_muVariable);
```

Otherwise change the member and argument to pointer or stl type as:

```
char *myVariable;
std::string myVariable;
std::vector<char> myVariable;
```